# In a VS Code extension, is there a way to set the configuration options for the editor (such as word wrap) programmatically?

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

For an extension I am working on, our end-users would prefer to have options such as word-wrap on by default. We would like to be able to set this at the language level *without* the user's direct involvement (just for the languages our extension is active for). I am aware of the per language settings. My goal is to set settings such as the following:

```
"[xml]": {
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.tabSize": 4
  },
```

*without* the user have to do so in their own user settings. Is there a way to do this via the [Extension API](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api)? I am not seeing any obvious ways to do so.

PS The [LanguageConfiguration object](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#LanguageConfiguration) does not seem to be relevant for setting things like word-wrap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, extensions can contribute default editor settings for a language  using `configurationDefaults` in the `package.json`

Here's what the builtin markdown extension [contributes](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/markdown/package.json#L218) for example:

```
{
    "name": "vscode-markdown",
    ...,
    "contributes": {
        "configurationDefaults": {
            "[markdown]": {
                "editor.wordWrap": "on",
                "editor.quickSuggestions": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This currently only supports `editor.*` language specific settings. We are tracking support for contributing additional language specific settings [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26707)

Answer (score 2):

Now you can change settings programmatically through the [`WorkspaceConfiguration` API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration):

```js
const configuration = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration()

const target = vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Workspace  // Update the setting locally
const overrideInLanguage = true  // Update the setting in the scope of the language

// Set the tab size to 4
configuration.update('editor.tabSize', 4, target, overrideInLanguage)
```